# Convert mxGraphModel XML to PNG on server side

Tags: mxgraph

I'm trying to integrate mxGraph in a small project and I would like to convert XML-files (with a mxGraphModel conatiner in it) stored on the server to PNG and PDF (and serve them as download).

I have the XML files on the server ready, but i can't find a possibility to convert them on server side (in a JAVA surflet) to PNG.

Here a sample XML-File:

```
<mxGraphModel>
    <root>
        <mxCell id="0"/>
        <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
        <mxCell id="2" value="Hello" parent="1" vertex="1">
            <mxGeometry x="20" y="20" width="80" height="30" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="3" value="World" parent="1" vertex="1">
            <mxGeometry x="200" y="150" width="80" height="30" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="4" value="" parent="1" source="2" target="3" edge="1">
            <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry"/>
        </mxCell>
    </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

Is there a way to do this on the server side ?

Best Regards,
Jens

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this using :

- the Xml2Svg demo program included in the draw.io source code, it converts mxgraph xml to svg file. Be carreful simple shapes are converted well, but not complex draw.io custom shapes
- Batik library to convert svg to a PNG file

PS : I also included this process into a mvn pdf:pdf custom Mojo with no success : the Batik library are in conflict between Batik and the pdf mojo

Didier